# Drill Down report in Jasperreports Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

In latest version of jasperreports studios (jasperserver ce 5.5.0a), I have a report with table results such as:

ID 2, 3, 44, 55, 66

How do I make these IDs clickable and used as a filter for another report?

I tried updating the text field hyperlink properties to ReportExecution and provided report parameters (_Report and parameter name for other report).  But this seemed to do nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First add hyperlink in the ID text field with ReportExecution property and provided report parameters, but for ID parameter  Expression should be text filed of ID means $F{ID}.

For more detail you can see this [Link](http://passionfordata.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-add-hyperlinks-in-jasper-server.html)